# How to display a thumbnail of product variation in custom table? I just make a custom variation table in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, product-variations

I created a custom variation table in WooCommerce, and I need to display product variations thumbnails in that custom table.

[image]

- What is it the right way?
- What is the code to create this?

Here is a sample code:

```php
<td> 
<?php 
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id ); 
$variations = $product->get_available_variations(); 
foreach ( $variations as $variation ) { 
    echo "<img src=" . $variation['image']['src'] .">"; 
} 
?> 
</td>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear: Please add the code of your custom table created in your question, with more details and explanations.

Comment: <td>
                    <?php
                        $product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
  echo "<img src=" . $variation['image']['src']  .">";
}
     ?> 
      
      </td>
      
      
I try this code and give the result on image